# How to restart ignite server with Spring config?

Tags: spring, ignite

I have Ignite server nodes in my application with the following configuration, and this application is clustered hence there can be multiple ignite servers.

Ignite config looks like this:

```java
@Bean
  public Ignite igniteInstance(JdbcIpFinderDialect ipFinderDialect, DataSource dataSource) {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setGridLogger(new Slf4jLogger());
    cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
    TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi()
        .setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder(ipFinderDialect).setDataSource(dataSource)
            .setInitSchema(false));
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfigurations.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[0]));
    cfg.setFailureDetectionTimeout(igniteFailureDetectionTimeout);
    return Ignition.start(cfg);
}
```

But at some point after running it for a day or so, ignite falls over with errors in line with the followings.

```
o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Node is out of topology (probably, due to short-time network problems
o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDiscoveryManager         : Local node SEGMENTED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=db3eb958-df2c-4211-b2b4-ba660bc810b0, addrs=[10.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[sd-9fdb-a8cb.nam.nsroot.net/10.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612755975209, loc=true, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=false]
ROOT                                     : Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SEGMENTATION, err=null]]
o.a.i.i.p.failure.FailureProcessor       : Ignite node is in invalid state due to a critical failure.
ROOT                                     : Stopping local node on Ignite failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SEGMENTATION, err=null]]
o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDiscoveryManager         : Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4d84f811-1c04-4f80-b269-a0003fbf7861, addrs=[10.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[sd-dc95-412b.nam.nsroot.net/10.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1612707966704, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=false]
o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor       : Stopped cache [cacheName=cacheOne]
o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor       : Stopped cache [cacheName=cacheTwo]
```

And whenever my applications' client nodes try to write in the server cache they fail with an error,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): cacheOne
```

**I am looking for a way to restart my Ignite Server node if it fails for such SEGMENTATION faults or any**, some suggestions say that I will have to implement AbstractFailureHandler and setFailureHandler as that implementation but failed to find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restart an Ignite server node, so if you're using it in a Spring context you need a new context (usually means restarting an application).

Client node will try to reconnect, but if it can't, the same will apply.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, been trying to implement AbstractFailureHandler :(

Comment: You can actually trigger application restart from FailureHandler, why not. Or use `RestartProcessFailureHandler`

Comment: Thanks, can you explain in further details, please? The application itself is deployed on WebServer (wildfly/jboss)

Comment: In this case you may need to write a FailureHandler which triggers redeployment of web application inside jboss (I used it by bumping modification date on application files, but maybe there is also an API).